# When installing CsvFormat in python:"No matching distribution found for CsvFormat" error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install CsvFormat package

I am using python 2.7.10

```
vm02$ pip install --user CsvFormat
```

Error is

```
Collecting CsvFormat
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement CsvFormat (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for CsvFormat

vm02$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
```

Comment: [There is no CsvFormat at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/CsvFormat/). What're you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

based on what I understand you are trying to read a csv file in python, The best way to do that is get `pandas` and then run the following command

```
import pandas
file = pandas.read_csv("Location of your file")
```

Check this link for More information [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/)

And if Ive misunderstood your question Please let me know.